# How to get line number

Tags: python, random, numbers, generator, line-numbers

So I made a random name generator but I want it to even print the line number of the name, So how do I get the line number?
Code:

```
import random

names = open(r"names.txt", "r")
name1 = readlines(names)
name = random.choice(name1)
names.close()

print(name)
```

So y'all got any ideas?

Comment: Instead of using `random.choice` you could just generate a random valid index of `name1`. Then use that to both get the name from `name1` and display the line number, which will be the index plus one. Makes sense?

Comment: What is `readlines(names)`? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

`enumerate()` is a method that adds a counter to an iterable and returns it as a new object. then you should convert it back to a `list` object.

```
import random

names = open(r"names.txt", "r")
name1 = readlines(names)
name = random.choice(list(enumerate(name1)))
names.close()

print(name)
```

if you want a line number you can do `enumerate(name1, 1)` to start counting from 1 instead of zero.

Comment: It doesn't add indexes, it returns a counter with the element in the form of a tuple

Comment: Also, it will be better if you included it in a separate function and returned the value. Then you could access the function any where

Comment: agreed, I'm not sure how the OP implemented it though, I'm using the code that he shared. I think you should comment this at the question comments section. I refered only the original problem which is to add the line number :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function like this:

```py
import random

def get_name():
    with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
        names   = f.readlines()
        i       = random.randint(0, len(names))
        return i, names[i].strip()

print(get_name())
```

The function returns two values where `i` is the index and the second is the name - you can use these two values to present the final output in many different ways.

Comment: Keep in mind that ```return i, names[i].strip()``` will return a tuple which you need to unpack later

Comment: if OP wants the line number in a string representation instead of a tuple, I am willing to change that.

Comment: No, I am telling you to unpack the tuple: ```i,j =get_name()```. That's all

Comment: OP should be able to use the function as is.

Comment: @Sujay surely a tuple can be printed without first being unpacked.